# CakePHP tutorial not seeing PostsController

Tags: cakephp

Im currently working on the cakephp tutorial, and have finished the first few steps. I've already added the post model controller(with the action) and view. For some reason though, when I go to www.mysite/posts/index I get a 404 error. I also noticed that the default www.mysite.com
says

*Error: PhpController could not be found.*

Any suggestions?

**/PostsController.php/**

```
<?php

class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }  
 }
```

I also have a PagesController.php in the same directory. I posted it here    http://jsfiddle.net/Z3jdu/
    ?>

Comment: if you have posts controller and index method that link it's ok. Pls post method from controller

Comment: You need to post your code, otherwise, we would be trying to help you blind.. Most likely it is a small error somewhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

i think u can find out by
Regarding pages controller never edit files in /cake/.. Override or extend them. 
By default you shouldn't need an index.php, you should enable mod rewrite and allow cake php to read the urls correctly
Try checking your .htaccess and server config to ensure .htaccess can be read.
at the end i should mention this Check your root, app and webroot directories to see if they actually contain a .htaccess file.
Ensure your apache server configuration actually has the following (seeing as it's localhost, allow everything?):

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

Ensure the following line is not commented with a hash tag (#)

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Hopefully your app will work and you can start the blog tutorial to learn more